# Unity3D on Click ignore all colliders accept the one on specific layer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, layer

I'm trying to make a simple drag and drop game where you have objects that can be picked up and if left above 1/2 of the screens height then it will fall down to high they will fall if you let them go below half of the screen they will stay there. Its a 2D game and what give the illusion of depth.

This is an image of the Thing i would like to make
[image]

Currently I can move the blue bucket from the bottom. If i lift the bucket above the PolygonCollider it will fall down to the Edge Collider 4. When i leave it somewhere withing the Polygone Colider i set the object to kinetic so it wont fall it will give the illusion that you placed it on the ground.

My problem is that the colliders of the bucket what I use to detect the click on it, will overlap with the PolygonCollider. And can sometimes the object is on top and sometime the polygoncollider , and if the polygoncollider is on top i can not lift the object.
 Is there a way to ignore  on click all layers except the PickebleObject layer that i use to identify the objects that can be picked up ?

**EDIT: here is my ObjectController script**

```
public LayerMask interactLayers;
public LayerMask ignoredColliders;
public Action<GameObject> OnDrag;
public Action<GameObject> OnLand;
private Rigidbody2D objRB2D;
private Vector2 MousePos;
private bool IsOnFloor = false;


private void Start()
{
    transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z - 0.1f);
    ignoredColliders = ~ignoredColliders;
    objRB2D = transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    objRB2D.gravityScale = GameManager.Instance.GlobalFallingSpeed;
}


private void OnMouseDown()
{
    objRB2D.isKinematic = true;
}

private void OnMouseDrag()
{
    MousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector2 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y ));
    //Limit So elements cant be moved out of the scene.
    float HorizontalClamp = Mathf.Clamp (MousePos.x, CameraControll.Instance.CamTopLeft.x, CameraControll.Instance.CamBottomRight.x);
    transform.position = new Vector3 (HorizontalClamp, MousePos.y, transform.position.z);

    //Check what is under the mouse.
    RaycastHit2D IsHoveringOver = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position,  transform.TransformDirection (Vector3.down), 0 , ignoredColliders);
    if (IsHoveringOver.transform != null) {
        if (GameManager.Instance.GroundColliders.value == LayerMask.GetMask (LayerMask.LayerToName (IsHoveringOver.transform.gameObject.layer)))
            IsOnFloor = true;
    }else IsOnFloor = false;


    RaycastHit2D HitColider = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position,  transform.TransformDirection (Vector3.down), Mathf.Infinity , ~ignoredColliders);

    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    if (HitColider.collider != null) {
        Debug.DrawLine( HitColider.point, transform.position, Color.magenta);
    }
    #endif
}

void OnMouseUp()
{
    if (!IsOnFloor) objRB2D.isKinematic = false;
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) {
    //Debug.Log(coll.gameObject.transform.name);
}
```

Comment: As you are talking about colliders you are using raycast to detect you "click" I presume, right? If not please show your pick-up logic.

Comment: Are you sure this is a layer issue and you are assigning the correct layers in the editor? You check the contents of the layermask to make sure that it is being set correctly. To check the binary contents you can use the following: `string binary1 = System.Convert.ToString (layersToIgnore.value, 2);Debug.Log ("Binary Layers to ignore: " + binary1);`

Comment: I do not select the objects by raycast. I only use raycast when i let go to see where did he placed it. Other then that I'm detecting if he clicked on the objects box collider. The result of your Log is : 11111111111111111111011111111111 (I need to ignore the GroundCllider layer which is in User position 8). My current fix is moving all draggble objects to -0.1 Z position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by using the Z axes to define wich of the colliders to be on top.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using physics raycast in your drag-n-drop logic take a look at this [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html), there you will find a topic about LayerMask and Raycasting.

Comment: Edited the question to include the Object Controller Script, I do use raycast  but I'm using the object OnMouseDown and Drag method to select the object. I made two raycast to see on what I'm hovering over and on what will it fall if let go. But i cant seem to make the ignoreLayer mask to work. As i know the ~ sign give you everything else then the one you selected. with out it it will only keep in mind that layer which you selected.Currently i made a quickfix that any pickeble object will will be moved to -0.1 Z cordoonates then its always above.But it seems to me that its a non pro solution.